# Is it possible to see DevExtreme app on Debug View Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, devextreme

I'm developing a hybird mobile application using `DevExtreme 17.2.5`.
My application uses `cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics` in order to collect custom events and to send them to a Firebase project.
I want to debug my application (especially the events collected) by using `DebugView`, a feature that comes with Firebase and allows you to collect realtime app events.
I deploy a test application (debug mode activated) using PhoneGap and then I debug it through Google Developer console. All this because it seems to be the only way to test my application.
The problem is that even if my app is on debug mode, it doesn't show app on Firebase's `DebugView`.
What could I do in order to see my app on `DebugView`?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you installed the app on a test device

1. Download and install ADB
2. Install ADB Driver and install device's driver your are going to use.
3. Open cmd or powershell and move to the folder where you saved `adb.exe`.
4. Execute the command `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>` to activate debug on your app.
5. Go to Firebase console\Debug View and you will find all the events that are happening in your app

In order to stop the debug mode on your device, run this command `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.`